# Change ImageView src from it's own onClick() method

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

I'm making a simple Whack a mole game, and when a user taps on a mole, I want it to turn into a poof before it disappears.  To do this, I'm trying to call setImageResource() from inside the onClick(), but onClick gets passed a View, which doesn't define setImageResource().  Casting the constructor object as an ImageView didn't work.  It returns 'can't resolve method' errors either way.

How do I do this?

```
public void onClick(View view) {                        
    view = (ImageView) view;
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.poof);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the variable view is still a `View`, which doesn't have the `setImageResource` method. You can create a new one of the type `ImageView` and use that one. It will work like this.

```
public void onClick(View view) {                        
    ImageView view1 = (ImageView) view;
    view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.poof);
}
```

Alternatly you could do it like this

```
public void onClick(View view) {                        
    ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.poof);
}
```

Comment: I was wondering why casting didn't work.  Looks like my syntax was off.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yea, that solved it.  You answered so quickly it wouldn't let me mark as the answer yet, but I marked it now.